# stuck accessing a method C++

Tags: c++, class, oop, object

I'm trying to recreate a cash register program. 
I have an employee object which has a name and a discount %

```
staffMember me ("tom", 20);
```

I want to apply the discount to the total of the cash register. My method works if I pass the discount as an integer parameter using me.getDiscountPercent like this

```
cashy.applyStaffDiscount(me.getDiscountPercent());

void cashRegister::applyStaffDiscount(int discount){
    total = (total/100)*(100-discount);
}
```

however I want to cin the staffMember name so I can have different staffMembers with different discounts. I did this which doesn't work

```
string employee;
cout << "Enter name: ";
cin >> employee;
cashy.applyStaffDiscount(employee);
```

the method:

```
void cashRegister::applyStaffDiscount(string employee){
total = (total/100)*(100-employee.getDiscountPercent());
}
```

Thanks Tom

Comment: employee is a string which doesn't have getDiscountPercent() method. If you have a base with names and discounts then write a method that will take name as parameter and return discount.

Comment: The data type for "employee" is string. The string class (from std namespace) doesn't have any method with the name "getDiscountPercent()".

Comment: You can store employees in a map where their name (string) is a key.

Answer (score 2):

The data type for `employee` is string. The `string` class (from `std` namespace) doesn't have any method with the name `getDiscountPercent()`. Perhaps, what you want to do is this:

```
string name;
int discount;

cout << "Enter name: ";
cin >> name;

cout << "Enter discount: ";
cin >> discount;

staffMember employee (name, discount); // <-- this is what you really want!

cashy.applyStaffDiscount(employee);
```

Answer (score 2):

The parameter `employee` is a `std::string`, not an `staffMember`. In your applyStaffDiscount function you have to pass an employee, not a string:

```
string employee_name;
int employee_discount;
cout << "Enter employee data: ";
cin >> employee_name;
cin >> employee_discount;

staffMember employee( employee_name , employee_discount); //Staff variable

cashy.applyStaffDiscount(employee);

/* ... */

void cashRegister::applyStaffDiscount(const staffMember& employee)
{
    total = (total/100)*(100-employee.getDiscountPercent());
}
```